# Google-fit: Requesting permissions for scope ./auth/fitness.activity.read triggers question about email, name, profile picture

Tags: flutter, google-oauth, google-fit

I am working on flutter app using Google Fit API to get information about users activity.
I used flutter plugins fit_kit or health to get the needful.

App is working. I created client ID. I went thru verification process and its basically ready for prime time. I have however one concern. When you launch the app its trying to get permission for the scope:

`./auth/fitness.activity.read`

First modal dialog leading to actual consent screen is asking me about sharing email, name and profile picture.

[image]

I don't have place in the code asking for access to google account's email, picture or name. Can this message be removed or altered to reflect actual situation?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change that message, it comes by default while choosing the Gmail account, however, after choosing the E-mail you should get something like below which says what data you are getting from that user

[image: fit_message]

As a workaround you can show a popup saying you need permission to access the steps data before asking the permission to choose the preferred Email, upon getting the permission from the user you can show the consent screen.

Comment: Did you found some place in official documentation where this is stated? I have same strong conviction like you but I am looking for some more evidence before I officially give up ;)